# Siri-like answers in Google Voice Search on 4.2

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, google-now, voice-recognition

On my Nexus 7 (4.2, all updates, German), I can start searches using speech in Google Now, but I can't get it to do anything else. In particular: It never opens cards when I ask about the weather for example, it never answers with speech, and it doesn't perform any commands (like call/text somebody). I've seen all these functions in videos promoting Jelly Bean features, and believe they should be there.

Basically, instead of working like Siri, I just have a search textbox with the voice input method.

I've searched the Play market, but didn't find anything that looked like it might help. How can I get Google Now / Voice Search to answer me?

Edit: If I switch the language to English, I get the Weather card (in a German-English mishmash), but I still don't get any spoken answers.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Google Now only supports certain languages at this moment in time.

You should change to a language that it supports (such as British English), using a locale changer application.